# Modify Device Configuration

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to implement Modify Device Configuration using Softlayer java API.
This process will be a similar process as purchase order. Is there any specific API to upgrade and downgrade device? I found getUpgradeRequest() for virtual guest. If you provide any sample code or API guide will be helpful.
Thank you 
[Modify Device Configuration Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUEhD.png)

```
        for (Guest guest :  Account.service(client).getVirtualGuests()){
            if(guest.getFullyQualifiedDomainName().equals(deviceName))  {
                Request rqt = Guest.service(client, guest.getId()).getUpgradeRequest();
                rqt.setId(id);
                rqt.setOrderId(orderId);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a Java example to upgrade a VSI. For Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.Order;
import com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.order.Property;
import com.softlayer.api.service.product.item.Price;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.Guest;
import com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.order.virtual.guest.Upgrade;

public class UpgradeVirtualGuest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String username = "set me";
        String apikey = "set me";

        // Set the Virtual Guest to upgrade
        Long vsiId = new Long(11498369);

       // Declare item prices. In this case I’m updating the RAM
       // Please set the new item Price

        Long[] prices = { new Long(1641)};  

        List<Property> properties = new ArrayList<Property>();
        Property maintenance = new Property(); 
        maintenance.setName("MAINTENANCE_WINDOW");
        maintenance.setValue("2015-10-05T9:00:00-05:00");
        properties.add(maintenance);

        Guest vsi = new Guest();
        vsi.setId(vsiId);

        String containerIdentifier = "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade";

        // Create a SoftLayer API client object
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apikey).withLoggingEnabled();


        /*
         * Set up Order template
         */
        Upgrade upgradeOrder = new Upgrade();

        upgradeOrder.setContainerIdentifier(containerIdentifier);
        upgradeOrder.getProperties().addAll(properties);
        upgradeOrder.getVirtualGuests().add(0, vsi);

        // Add Item prices to list
        for (Long i : prices) {
            Price price = new Price();
            price.setId(new Long(i));
            upgradeOrder.getPrices().add(price);
        }


        try 
        {
            Order orderResult = com.softlayer.api.service.product.Order.service(client).verifyOrder(upgradeOrder);
            System.out.println("order successfully verified: " + orderResult);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

How to get the available prices for the Virtual guest to upgrade?
Execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[virtual_guest_ID]/getUpgradeItemPrices

Method: GET
```

**References:**

> https://forums.softlayer.com/forum/softlayer-developer-network/general-discussion/84916-changing-virtual-guest-maxmemory
>   (This is a forum that will be outdated soon, but it help you now)
>   https://sldn.softlayer.com/es/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade
>   http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order

**Other examples:**

> https://softlayer.github.io/php/upgrade_virtual_guest/
>   https://gist.github.com/underscorephil/3790139
>   https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/softlayer/api/example/OrderVirtualServer.java
>   https://softlayer.github.io/

Regards