# Network Speed - How to find the ID from getItemPrices to increase maxspeed in softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am following the below steps to increase the network maxspeed to 1 gbps,

1. Find the package ID using the API:

   ```
   https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$vsi/getObject?objectMask=mask[billingItem[package]]
   ```
2. Next I need to get the Item price ID for 1 gbps speed and using following API:

   ```
   https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/$packageId/getItemPrices
   ```

This is where am stuck as am not aware which ID needs to selected from this output. I need to increase the speed to 1gbps (private network). I see more than one ID for this in the output.

I'd like some help in identifying the right `ID` so I can proceed to increase max speed with a upgrade request.

Answer (score 0):

This request will help you to get valid item prices to upgrade your Virtual Server:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[vsi_id]/getUpgradeItemPrices
Method: GET
```

In the result should display something like this:

```
{
"currentPriceFlag": false
"hourlyRecurringFee": ".04"
"id": 274
"itemId": 188
"laborFee": "0"
"locationGroupId": null
"onSaleFlag": null
"oneTimeFee": "0"
"quantity": null
"recurringFee": "20"
"setupFee": "0"
"sort": 3
"accountRestrictions": [0]
"categories": [1]
0:  {
"categoryCode": "port_speed"
"id": 26
"name": "Uplink Port Speeds"
"quantityLimit": 0
}-
-
"item": {
"capacity": "1000"
"description": "1 Gbps Public & Private Network Uplinks"
"id": 188
"itemTaxCategoryId": 166
"keyName": "1_GBPS_PUBLIC_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINKS"
"softwareDescriptionId": null
"units": "Mbps"
"upgradeItemId": null
"attributes": [0]
}-
}
```

The id that we need is 274 (Using a Test Account and valid for my VSI)
Now, to upgrade the Virtual Guest, please execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

Method: POST

{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade",
      "prices": [
        {
          "id": 274
        }
      ],
      "virtualGuests": [
        {
          "id": 11498369
        }
      ],
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "NOTE_GENERAL",
          "value": "upgrading speed"
        },
        {
          "name": "MAINTENANCE_WINDOW",
          "value": "2015-10-05T9:00:00-05:00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Where: “11498369” is the vsi_id to upgrade

**Reference:**
[Modify Device Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197429/modify-device-configuration)

Then, if you want to change the private/public network interface speed to the new speed:
Execute (Example for private network speed):

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[vsi_id]/setPrivateNetworkInterfaceSpeed.json

Method: POST
{
    "parameters": [    
      10
    ]
}
```

**References:**

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/setPrivateNetworkInterfaceSpeed
>
> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/setPublicNetworkInterfaceSpeed

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried the same and I get this exception when I try to verify order, "<root><error>An internal system error has occurred.</error><code>SoftLayer_Exception_InternalError</code></root>"

Comment: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade",
      "prices": [
        {
          "id": 23777
        }
      ],
      "virtualGuests": [
        {
          "id": 15917215
        }
      ],
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "NOTE_GENERAL",
          "value": "upgrading speed"
        },
        {
          "name": "MAINTENANCE_WINDOW",
          "value": "now"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

Comment: After reviewing your Json configuration, it is missing a " }" at the end of this. I mean, you set " ..."value": "now" } ] } ] ", but it has be " ... "value": "now" } ] } ] } ". Please, change it and let me know if you have any problem :).

Comment: Well am still facing the same issue :-(

Comment: Any help on this is highly appreciated as am stranded at this point

Comment: @MalaKannan, I executed a "VerifyOrder" using the same json configuration than you, and the execution is ok. Try this:  
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade",
      "prices": [
        {
          "id": 23777
        }
      ],
      "virtualGuests": [
        {
          "id": 15917215
        }
      ],
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "NOTE_GENERAL",
          "value": "upgrading speed"
        },
        {
          "name": "MAINTENANCE_WINDOW",
          "value": "now"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: To confirm if the json configuration is well formed, please verify it using this online tool: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/  .Then, you can try to execute your request, using "Advanced Rest Client Application" for Chrome. In some cases it gives us more information in the error messages when our request is not ok.

Comment: Thanks a ton, it worked fine. I had to use .json in the API when posting the request using POSTER

Comment: It's good to know that it helped you. Please up-vote if you want :). Thanks.

Comment: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/<runtimeID>/getUpgradeItemPrices?objectFilter={"item": {"item": {"keyName": {"operation": "1_GBPS_PUBLIC_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINKS"} } }} am using this to filter by this keyName but it does not filter it. Am I wrong with my filter. Kindly help

Comment: could you help with this

Comment: My apologies @MalaKannan, I was not able to get filtered data. I tried some filters but all items are returned. I'm afraid the filters cannot be applied to this. But If I have any new about this, I'll tell you. Sorry :(