# How to set 10G and 20G network interface speeds on SoftLayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using SoftLayer_Hardware_Server.setPublicNetworkInterfaceSpeed() to change the public interface speed of bare metal servers.  I am unable to set any speed higher than 2000 (1G bonded).

Trying to set speed to 10000 results in an exception:

> SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): Speed cannot be null
>   and must be 0 (Disconnect), 10, 100, or 1000.

Setting the speed to 20000 results in a different exception:

> SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): Speed cannot be null
>   and must be 0 (Disconnect), 1000, or 2000.

Is there a different nomenclature for 10G and 20G?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SoftLayer API does not permit any speeds higher than 2000 for bare metal systems.  I have reported the bug to SoftLayer support.

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to see what is `max speed` set in your server. Please execute the following rest example to see that information:

  ```
  https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware/[hardware_id]/getNetworkComponents?objectMask=mask[id,name,hardware,speed,maxSpeed,port]

  Method: GET
  ```

Also you can see these hardware details (`Speed`,`Max speed`) on `Control Portal` (i.e. https://control.softlayer.com/devices/details/1234)  and values are allowed/available to set.

- Now, if you need to increase the `speed`, the next step is to `modify Max Speed`. In other words, the server has to be upgraded and see what `max values` are allowed to set.

  This is example to `upgrade the max speed`for `Virtual Guests`: [Network Speed - How to find the ID from getItemPrices to increase maxspeed in softlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358461/network-speed-how-to-find-the-id-from-getitemprices-to-increase-maxspeed-in-so)

  Where method to get valid item prices to upgrade for Bare Metal is [SoftLayer_Hardware::getUpgradeItemPrices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware/getUpgradeItemPrices)

  And the`complexType` to change in the `Hardware upgrade execution` is `"complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server_Upgrade"`.
- Then, you will able to change the `speed` until `max speed` set in you server.

Comment: The server is already capable of 10G and 20G speeds.

The same exceptions are also shown when changing the speeds to anything higher than 2000 in the portal.

Comment: It seems to be more than API problem, please open SL ticket in order to isolate the problem. Regards.