# Set baremetal server maximum port speed execption

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Follow the answer 
[How to set 10G and 20G network interface speeds on SoftLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360200/how-to-set-10g-and-20g-network-interface-speeds-on-softlayer)
[How to set 10G and 20G network interface speeds on SoftLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360200/how-to-set-10g-and-20g-network-interface-speeds-on-softlayer)
to set maximum speed for baremetal server with following code:

```
var sess = session.New(userName, apiKey, endpoint)  

order := datatypes.Container_Product_Order{ 
    ComplexType: sl.String("SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server_Upgrade"),        
    Hardware: []datatypes.Hardware{
        {
            Id : sl.Int(SERVER_ID),              
        },
    },
    Prices: []datatypes.Product_Item_Price{
        {Id : sl.Int(35666)},  // Port maximum speed to "1 Gbps Dual Public & Private Network Uplinks (Unbonded)""
    },
    Properties: []datatypes.Container_Product_Order_Property {
        {
            Name: sl.String("MAINTENANCE_WINDOW"),
            Value: sl.String("2018-08-21T14:00:00+08:00"),
        },
        {
            Name: sl.String("orderOrigin"),
            Value: sl.String("control"),
        },
        {
            Name: sl.String("MAINTENANCE_WINDOW_ID"),
            Value: sl.String("189467"),
        },
    },
}

service := services.GetProductOrderService(sess)
resp, err := service.VerifyOrder(&order)
if err != nil{
    fmt.Println(err)
}else{
    fmt.Printf("Set speed status: %v \n",resp)
}
```

The price ID was got from HardwareServerService.GetUpgradeItemPrices().
The VerifyOrder function return error:

> SoftLayer_Exception_Order_InvalidContainer: Invalid container specified: SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order. Ordering a server or service requires a specific container type, not the generic base order container. (HTTP 500)

What's wrong in the Container_Product_Order object?

Answer (score 0):

If you add `sess.Debug := true` after creation of the session you will be able to retrieve logs from go-client, on this case the client is sending `SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order` instead of `SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server_Upgrade`:

```
2018/08/21 18:44:50 [DEBUG] Request URL:  POST https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder.json
2018/08/21 18:44:50 [DEBUG] Parameters:  {"parameters":[{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order","hardware":[{"id":11112222333}],"prices":[{"id":35666}],"properties":[{"name":"MAINTENANCE_WINDOW","value":"2018-08-21T14:00:00+08:00"},{"name":"orderOrigin","value":"control"},{"name":"MAINTENANCE_WINDOW_ID","value":"189467"}]}]}
```

So I recommend to modify the order skeleton in order to upgrade the baremetal, try with the following:

```golang
order := datatypes.Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server_Upgrade{    
        Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server: datatypes.Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server{    
            Container_Product_Order: datatypes.Container_Product_Order{    
                Hardware: []datatypes.Hardware{    
                    {    
                        Id: sl.Int(SERVER_ID),    
                    },    
                },    
                Prices: []datatypes.Product_Item_Price{    
                    {Id: sl.Int(35666)}, // Port maximum speed to "1 Gbps Dual Public & Private Network Uplinks (Unbonded)""    
                },    
                Properties: []datatypes.Container_Product_Order_Property{    
                    {    
                        Name:  sl.String("MAINTENANCE_WINDOW"),    
                        Value: sl.String("2018-08-21T14:00:00+08:00"),    
                    },    
                    {    
                        Name:  sl.String("orderOrigin"),    
                        Value: sl.String("control"),    
                    },    
                    {    
                        Name:  sl.String("MAINTENANCE_WINDOW_ID"),    
                        Value: sl.String("189467"),    
                    },    
                },    
            },    
        },    
    }
```

Comment: It works well. But the order status is 'Pending Sales Approval'. When the order will be approved or auto approved? Or do I need to do further actions for it?

Comment: Orders pending approval will go into the sales pending order queue. These orders did not achieve auto approval status or were transitioned to pending approval from another pending status

Comment: That means your order needs to be approved by Sales. There should be a ticket open, so you can track the status of your order through it.