# Softlayer API: Is it possible to get a related orderId with the ticketId?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

What I'm trying to do is to get a related order id after installing security SW through ticket.
Actually I've seen the following API Account-getUpgradeRequests.

[SoftLayer_Account::getUpgradeRequests](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getUpgradeRequests)

But this API seems to be appliable to only "Sales" group tickets.
How can I get an related order Id from "Support" group tickets? What API I shoud use?

Answer (score 0):

Well basically, the method returns all the upgrade requests. When you upgrade a device this ticket is created automatically and it contains the orderId for your upgrade request.

The upgrade requests are usually created using the groups: "Hardware" or "Sales".

So, I do not know how your ticket was generated, but If you created manually the ticket with a orderId in the "ticket body" field, the getUpgradeRequests will not list that ticket, and there is not any method which lists that. You could list all the tickets and look up in their body the orderID.

Comment: I created the ticket with createUpgradeTicket service of Ticket. So the group was "Sales" when the ticket was created. But after several ticket updates,  the group is changed to "Support". I guess that support guy changes the group manullay. So, how about this case? Thanks.

Comment: the upgrade request created by createUpgradeTicket method is not displayed by the getUpgradeRequest method. the tickets displayed by getUpgradeRequest method are the one created when you go to the portal page and click "Modify device configuracion" the equivalent to that using the API is calling the placerOrder() method see this forum related to that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197429/modify-device-configuration